# When burning Metal Salts such as Lithium Chloride is the emission toxic?

Tags: metal

I'm completely new; Just thought this was the place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Burning is the wrong word. Lithium chloride or sodium chloride cannot burn. If the temperatute is high enough it can melt and later vaporize. For harzard conditions you can read MSDS sheet for the compounds.

https://www.atmos.umd.edu/~russ/MSDS/lithium_chloride.htm